# Keep users that visited the website more than one day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like the following:

| date | user |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | James |
| 2020-01-02 | James |
| 2020-02-03 | Sarah |
| 2020-03-05 | Charlie |
| 2020-03-05 | Charlie |
| 2020-03-06 | Charlie |
| 2020-04-01 | Susan |
| 2020-04-01 | Susan |

What I am trying to do is to keep the users who visited the website more than one day (not more than once). Based on the table above, I should only keep James and Charlier and leave out Sarah and Susan.
Sarah should be left out because she visited the website only once in one day and Susan should be left out because she visited the website twice, but only in one day.

Could you help how it can be done?

Comment: have you tried at least something? show us some efforts and what the problem is? so we can help rather than just do you homework!

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `DISTINCT` to find unique records before using a group by and having clause to filter the users who visited multiple days

```sql
SELECT
    username
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        username,
        date
    FROM
        my_table
) t
GROUP BY 
    username
HAVING
    COUNT(username) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select username
from t
group by username
having min(date) <> max(date);
```

If you want the original rows, use qualify:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1=1
qualify count(distinct date) over (partition by username) > 1;
```

Or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.username = t.username and t2.date <> t.date
             );
```